# Limit 1 session per user in sharepoint page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, session, cookies

We're developing a video site that will be on sharepoint,
we want to limit the users to be able to watch 1 video at a time.
The limitations I have for this:
-Enable session state is not active in the farm

The things I do have control on: 
-Master page 
-The code itself(the video webpart etc)

The problem with Cookies for instance, is when to delete them,
I override "unload" and "dispose" events of the webparts and the page.Request wasn't available in that context

If there are solutions with Session - do suggest, but I prefer solution without the need to activate it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difficult is to determinate that the user is the same or different, and then know if is see a video or not. Why do you belive that you have so cool videos that your user won to see more than 1 at the time :) I mean... you afraid about bandwidth ? or for hackers ?

Comment: Bandwidth..it's a requirement that came from my supervisor 
As for identifying that the video is played or not- lets say it will be in the page level(if the user is inside of a video page- even if the video is finished and stopped playing the user won't be able to open another page with video)

Comment: Check this http://www.iis.net/download/BitRateThrottling

Comment: Our servers run windows server 2003 - means it doesn't stand in the requirements of the extension(OS and IIS version)

Answer (score 0):

found the solution for anyone who's looking:
first I put a check if there's an existing cookie on the relevant webparts, if not I create those webparts as usual and create the cookie
Second I registered the event "onunload" of the body element in the masterpage,
there I put javascript that called webservice which is responsible of clearing the created cookie- only if it was created from the same location who called the "onunload" event(I kept the url as value in the cookie)

If session is usable- the solution is the same just keeping the data in the session

Thanks for your comments